# Creating an array from values in a loop

Tags: javascript

I have a loop that looks like this:

```
var selectionList = document.querySelectorAll(".product");

selectionList.forEach(selectionItem => {
    var selectionItemTitle = selectionItem.querySelector(".product-title");
}
```

Inside of my loop I want to ad a condition that says "If this title is not equal to NONE, add this to an array with all the others. See below my note in the code:

```
selectionList.forEach(selectionItem => {
    var selectionItemTitle = selectionItem.querySelector(".product-title");
    if(selectionItemTitle.textContent != 'None'){
        
        // this is where I am stuck (I don't know what to add inside of my condition)

    }
}
```

Basically what I want to do is, all the "selectionItemTitle" that passes the conditon needs to be added to an array so I can use that array some place else.

Is this even possible?

*Quick note: The reason why I am using a loop, is because I have lots of other code in it (the above is just an example). So I really want to stick to the loop.*

Comment: You're stuck on adding items to an array? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: I don't think I understand your question. You can create your array before the `forEach` and then use `push` if the `if` condition is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can create your array and then add to it with `push`, see comments:

```
const theArray = []; // *** Create the array
selectionList.forEach(selectionItem => {
    var selectionItemTitle = selectionItem.querySelector(".product-title");
    if(selectionItemTitle.textContent != 'None'){
        
        theArray.push(selectionItemTitle); // *** Add to it

    }
});
```

But that's if you want to keep the `forEach`. You could use `filter` instead, still doing the other work in the `filter` callback:

```
const theArray = [...selectionList].filter(selectionItem => {
    var selectionItemTitle = selectionItem.querySelector(".product-title");
    // At the end, decide whether this entry is kept or discarded
    // (true for keep, false for discard)
    return selectionItemTitle.textContent != 'None';
});
```

Note the spread so that we turn the `NodeList` from `querySeletorAll` into a true array (so it has `filter`). You can also just use `filter` directly on the `NodeList`:

```
const theArray = Array.prototype.filter.call(selectionList, selectionItem => {
    var selectionItemTitle = selectionItem.querySelector(".product-title");
    // At the end, decide whether this entry is kept or discarded
    // (true for keep, false for discard)
    return selectionItemTitle.textContent != 'None';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare a variable and assign it an empty array.
While looping, if the condition is met, push into the empty array.